# TEX - Mysql UTF8_Data Storage issue

Tags: latex, tex

Iam trying to store Latex expression to Mysql Database, I have selected the encoding to UTF8_General. The tex expression block is as follows

```
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,n} \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \cdots & a_{2,n} \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
a_{m,1} & a_{m,2} & \cdots & a_{m,n}
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
```

While iam trying to save to Mysql database, all the text gets copied fine except for the \b character which gets truncated. Does anyone know the reason for the same.

Here is the code that gets stored in the database

```
$$
egin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & cdots & a_{1,n} \
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & cdots & a_{2,n} \
vdots  & vdots  & ddots & vdots  \
a_{m,1} & a_{m,2} & cdots & a_{m,n}
end{pmatrix} 
$$
```

While i thought this maybe due to C escape syntax that Mysql uses why does only the starting \b characters get truncated while the rest of the \c and \d characters remain intact.

Does anyone know wha the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL interprets `\b` as a backspace character. It doesn't interpret `\c` or `\d` as anything special. You need to fix your quoting on insert to account for this.

See also [this list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences) of all of the MySQL escapes.

Comment: Great, So just converting the text to \\b should work. Thanks!